# Pandas & MatPlotLib: Plot a Bar Graph on Existing Scatter Plot or Vice Versa

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a line graph (plotted using plot(x,y) funstion) plotted in a window, then, would it be possible to Plot a bar graph in/on the same window for visual analysis of the data that was plotted?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG Firstly i tried plotting both graphs and then calling "plt.show()" in the end hoping it would draw them both on single window... Didn't work. Then tried using "ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)" but couldn't figure that out and am now stuck here.

Comment: This is a simple, straightforward question. A simple edit would likely merit a more positive response, for instance adding the comment made shortly after in the question window. The number of times viewed in nearly 3 years testifies to the question's legitimacy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to work a little harder and use the `axes` of the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x= np.arange(5)
y1=np.arange(5)
y2 = np.ones(5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y1)
ax.bar(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. This works for me. Thanks for the hint/push in the right direction

Comment: But what if x isn't a sequence of integers?

Answer (score 0):

In response to [Mattice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5661399/mattice-verhoeven), either resetting an index or toying with axis settings plot parameters will satisfy a non-integer request.

Allow me to demo:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as DF
import calendar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cells = {2006: [ 14.0223, 1.7171, 192.08],
         2005: [ 5.1542, 0.6657, 28.5],
         2004: [ 3.3514, 2.2503, 191.83],
         2003: [ 9.1817, 0.4751, 143.83],
         2002: [ 9.9821, 2.2136, 191.91],
         2001: [ 13.701, 2.6296, 50],
         1912: [ 8.5796, 4.4859, 191.91],
         1911: [ 7.2977, 2.0956, 176.06],
         1910: [ 3.9382, 3.1705, 112.19],
         1909: [ 6.8692, 1.9548, 10.83]}
sprint = DF.from_dict(cells, orient="index", columns=['A', 'B', 'cost'])
sprint['total_data'] = sprint.A + sprint.B

sprint = DF.from_dict(cells, orient="index", columns=['A','B','cost'])
sprint['total_data'] = sprint.A + sprint.B
sprint.reset_index(inplace=True)
sprint['Month'] = sprint['index'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[int(str(x)[-2:])])
sprint['Year'] = sprint['index'].apply(lambda x: 2000 + int(str(x)[:2]))
```

I convert the index to string, but the same could work with integers if they are unique. This method will work by simply making the index into a string, by using `sprint.index = sprint.index.astype(str)`.

```
sprint.index = sprint.Year.astype(str) + ' ' + sprint.Month
```

I tried printing lines in one plot using the line,

> sprint.plot(y=['A','B','total_data'], use_index=True)

However, I found I needed to add the bar plot to the scatter plot, so had to go with another method using `ax.plot`, opposed to the DataFrame's built-in method. From here, I parse out two plots, using `add_subplot`. I needed to parse the columns in a for loop to label properly.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in ['A','B','total_data']: ax.plot(sprint.index, sprint[i], label=i)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xticks(rotation = 70)
```

Then I was able to add the secondary bar plot with its own y-axis and legend, while using the same x-axis.

```
axB = ax.twinx()
axB.bar(sprint.index, sprint.cost, fill=False, label='cost')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]